# Como resolver o problema do printf no meu código? (Ele não imprime saída)

Tags: c, criptografia

O objetivo do código é quebrar a cifra de Vigenère, usando o método de Kasiski para encontrar o comprimento da chave, análise de frequência para descobrir a chave. E acontece que não sei o porquê dele não estar imprimindo a saída no console, dado que ele não apresenta nenhum erro quando compilado.

Eu queria que ele apresentasse a mensagem de entrada decifrada na saída. A saída decifrada esperada é "David" e a chave é "chave". Revisei o código, porém com meus conhecimentos atuais não consegui resolver o problema. Segue abaixo o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Função para calcular o índice de coincidência de um texto
double calculateIndexOfCoincidence(char *text, int len) {
    int letterCount[26] = {0};

    // Conta a frequência de cada letra no texto
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isalpha(text[i])) {
            char c = toupper(text[i]);
            letterCount[c - 'A']++;
        }
    }

    // Calcula o índice de coincidência
    double ic = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        ic += (double)(letterCount[i] * (letterCount[i] - 1)) / (len * (len - 1));
    }

    return ic;
}

// Função para encontrar o tamanho da chave usando o método de Kasiski
int findKeyLength(char *ciphertext) {
    int lenCiphertext = strlen(ciphertext);
    int maxKeyLength = 20; // Máximo comprimento da chave a ser verificado (suposição)

    // Inicializa um array para armazenar as distâncias entre sequências iguais
    int *distances = (int *)malloc(lenCiphertext * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < lenCiphertext; i++) {
        distances[i] = 0;
    }

    // Encontra sequências iguais e calcular as distâncias entre elas
    for (int i = 0; i < lenCiphertext; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < lenCiphertext; j++) {
            if (strncmp(ciphertext + i, ciphertext + j, maxKeyLength) == 0) {
                distances[j - i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Encontra o maior divisor comum das distâncias
    int keyLength = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < maxKeyLength; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < lenCiphertext; j++) {
            if (distances[j] >= i) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            keyLength = i;
        }
    }

    free(distances);
    return keyLength;
}

// Função para encontrar a chave usando análise de frequência
void findKeyWithFrequencyAnalysis(char *ciphertext, int keyLength, char *foundKey) {
    int lenCiphertext = strlen(ciphertext);

    for (int k = 0; k < keyLength; k++) {
        double maxIC = 0.0;
        char bestChar = 'A';

        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            char *subtext = (char *)malloc(lenCiphertext);
            int subtextLen = 0;

            // Coleta letras em intervalos de tamanho keyLength
            for (int i = k; i < lenCiphertext; i += keyLength) {
                subtext[subtextLen++] = (ciphertext[i] - c + 26) % 26 + 'A';
            }

            subtext[subtextLen] = '\0';
            double ic = calculateIndexOfCoincidence(subtext, subtextLen);

            if (ic > maxIC) {
                maxIC = ic;
                bestChar = c;
            }

            free(subtext);
        }

        foundKey[k] = bestChar;
    }

    foundKey[keyLength] = '\0';
}

// Função para decifrar a cifra de Vigenère
void decryptVigenere(char *ciphertext, char *foundKey, char *plaintext) {
    int lenCiphertext = strlen(ciphertext);
    int keyLength = strlen(foundKey);

    for (int i = 0; i < lenCiphertext; i++) {
        char c = ciphertext[i];
        char k = foundKey[i % keyLength];

        if (isalpha(c)) {
            char base = islower(c) ? 'a' : 'A';
            plaintext[i] = ((c - k + 26) % 26) + base;
        } else {
            plaintext[i] = c;
        }
    }

    plaintext[lenCiphertext] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char ciphertext[] = "FHVDH"; // Texto cifrado

    int keyLength = findKeyLength(ciphertext);
    char foundKey[keyLength + 1];
    findKeyWithFrequencyAnalysis(ciphertext, keyLength, foundKey);

    char plaintext[strlen(ciphertext) + 1];
    decryptVigenere(ciphertext, foundKey, plaintext);

    printf("Chave encontrada: %s\n", foundKey);
    printf("Texto decifrado: %s\n", plaintext);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A função `findKeyLength` está retornando o valor zero, assim `foundkey` será criada com nenhum elemento.

```
int keyLength = findKeyLength(ciphertext);
char foundKey[keyLength + 1]; /// keyLength tem valor zero
                              /// foundkey igual nulo

// Função para decifrar a cifra de Vigenère
void decryptVigenere(char *ciphertext   , 
                     char *foundKey     , 
                     char *plaintext   ) 
{
  int lenCiphertext = strlen(ciphertext);
  int keyLength     = strlen(foundKey  );

  for (int i = 0; i < lenCiphertext; i++) 
  {
    char c = ciphertext[i];
    char k = foundKey[i % keyLength]; /// keyLength contem o valor zero
                                      /// erro, local de memoria invalido
                                      /// quando i for zero (0 % 0) = nao 
                                      /// se pode dividir por zero
    if (isalpha(c)) 
    {
      char base = islower(c) ? 'a' : 'A';
      plaintext[i] = ((c - k + 26) % 26) + base;
    } 
    else 
    {
      plaintext[i] = c;
    }
  }
  plaintext[lenCiphertext] = '\0';
}
```